# Django's authenticate method returns 'None' for a an already saved User

Tags: python, django, django-1.11

**Settings.py**

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
        'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```

**Tests.py which has the code triggering the error**

```
class LoginTest(TestCase):

    def test_can_redirect_to_user_page_if_authentificated(self):
        test_user = User(username='foo', password='bar', first_name='Testy', last_name='McTestingTon', email='testy@email.com', is_active=True)
        test_user.save()
        current_user = authenticate(username=test_user.username, password=test_user.password)
        print(current_user)

        response = self.client.post('/login', data = {'username' : current_user.username, 'password' : current.password})
        self.assertEqual(response.url, '/users/Testy')
```

`current_user` is always returned as `None`

I've tried numerous advices from other posts here on SO but authenticate still returns None for a user whose `is_active` I've explicitly set to `True` and with the `ModelBackend` added to my `settings.py`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`create_user`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_user) to create a user, saving a `User` object directly will not encrypt the password so will never authenticate

```
test_user = User.objects.create_user(...)
```